# mysql multistatement query problem(if one query fail how we rollback)

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql c api for database interaction, I want to know that if one query of Mysql multi statement fail then how we roll back all query which successfully executed..
ex-
mysql_query(conn,"select * from account_db; select count(*) from account_dbb;select * from account_db")
if there are a scenario where queries are dependent to each other and here if one query fail then related other query should be rollback for making database consistency
,[ mysql multi statement execute query one by one so how we will check all query will be run , if all can be run, then only process continue]
Here in this example , second query is wrong, i want to do, if anyone query fail, no changes should be occour in database, is this possible?

Comment: Why you want to "rollback" SELECT queries?

Comment: i m sorry to use wrong syntax, i just write it, replace select to insert then it seems fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i got one solution of this, i need to use transaction here, for reading transaction go->
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm
so my query will look like-
mysql_query(conn,"begin;select * from account_db; select count(*) from account_dbb;select * from account_db;commit")

and where in the code u got one query fail there we can write

mysql_query(conn,"rollback");

mysql_query(conn,"commit");

now if any query failed all query updation will be rollback.............